# Are Microsoft Azure SQL Federation services covered by the SQL Azure SLA, or is it currently in CTP?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, sla, federated

I can't seem to find a definitive answer for this. Are the new SQL Azure Federated Database features covered by the SQL Azure SLA? Or are these features still considered to be in CTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure SQL Federations have been live, in production, for 6 months.

Initial announcement post from 6 months ago is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/12/12/sql-azure-federations-is-open-for-business.aspx). Three weeks ago, [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2012/06/14/federations-what-s-next-announcements-from-teched-2012.aspx) went live, describing the latest released features of Federations, as well as roadmap plans. Among these roadmap features are federation composition/decomposition via `ALTER FEDERATION` and point-in-time restore.